# Single page web application design approach

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, single-page-application

Before begin, I have very little experience/knowledge in webpage development and have intermediate knowledge in common programming languages.

I'm learning AngularJS(JavaScript)/HTML/CSS and trying to build a single page application and I have JSON API resource(For example, http://..../Month/Day.json)

In the application, I'd like to have 2 or more Displays (For example, Overview and Detailed view)

My first question is, if end-user would switches to Detailed View from Main View.. how should HTML file be structured, if two kinds of views will have **completely different display structure** ? (once again, my knowledge in HTML is newbie)

Second question is, if I need to retrieve different JSON file (or data) based on some JavaScript property/value.  How can I achieve this using AngularJS?  I know $http method retrieves one JSON file, but how can I make this request again with different URL?

Cheers and have a great weekend!

Comment: This question is broad. Try to start building the app, and when you run into something you get stuck on post a question specifically about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be achieved with **UI-Routing** as said earlier.

How ever there are few additional configurations which enables you to achieve this.To be specific rather than exploring entire module. Begin with these

First case,

- You have List of students in your **Index.html**
- Click on a studentName -> navigates to **studentDetails.html**
- In this case there is a property called **RESOLVE** using which you
  can pre populate the data even **before navigation**.

  [Clear Explanation is given here](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c#.vac0lfats)

Second case,

- You have two sections which should be shown to some users and hided
  to some users in a page called classDetails.html
- If some Student is viewing he should not be able to see staff
  information of the class.
- If a staff is viewing he/she should see the entire class details.
- To solve this we have property called **NAMED VIEWS** in **ui-routing**
- Both are different views but will use same Controller. Also Explore about (**Abstract states**)
      [Sample Demo with code](http://websystique.com/angularjs/angularjs-routing-tutorial-using-ui-router/)

For your second Question please find the below code snippet.

Create a **service** which can be reused by injecting in controller as a dependency

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('dataService', function ($http) {
    var connectionurl = 'http://localhost:8000/';
    return {
        ////Common Service call for json files
        getJsonContent: function (jsonfileName, successcallback) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: connectionurl + jsonfileName + '.json'
            })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                successcallback(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //error handling
            })
        }
    }
});
```

**Using the above service in your controller**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, dataService) {

    ////Function triggered on some event
    $scope.someFunction= function (value_changed_in_view) {
        if (value_changed_in_view)
        {
            dataService.getJsonContent("jsonfileA",function (successcall) {
                $scope.variable_name= successcall;
            })
        }
        else {
            dataService.getJsonContent("jsonfileB",function (successcall) {
                $scope.variable_name= successcall;
            })

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Since you have mentioned you are using Angular JS, you can use Angular JS features like ng-route/ui-route. This enables user to load multiple views inside same page. For the HTML part you can create simple navbar with the options Main and Detailed View which will load different views.

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

The above div will load the content from your view i.e whenever state or url matches under your ng/ui route its going to incorporate that html inside the above div.It could be main or detailed here.
Below link will help you understand more:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

2 ) For the second question, I am not sure I get you completely. If you want to load different JSON, you can define the different function inside the controller in angular JS and call the required JSON file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  That definitely answers my first question.  I guess I wasn't so clear about the second question.  Please let me rephrase it, so if I first load up /1-1.json, but then user wants to see the different data from /1-2.json and so on...if I have millions of json files, I can't put all these urls into diff functions I believe.  I can think of creating var urlBuilder = "http://..."+firstNum+"/"+secondNum;   ... is this the correct or most efficient method to deal with multiple JSON files?

Answer (score -1):

```
 A simple Single Page Application using AngularJs.
```

[**Download**](https://github.com/umakantmane/single-page-app)

```
Extract and execute in your local machine which will give you little idea about SPA
```